# Weird visual artifacts in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, visual-artifacts

I have a weird question. I installed `google chrome-stable` from ubuntu repository:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

It looks like a normal installation of google chrome. But there is a problem. I get weird graphical artifacts:

[image]

What could be the cause? Firefox works perfectly.

System Specs: i3-6100, 240 SSD, Integrated Graphical Card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of visual artifact was wrong drivers installed on Ubuntu 16.04 to Intel HD Graphics. I `-purge` these drivers: `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and after this chrome start work perfectly. The removal of the drivers did not affect in any way the performance of the equipment or displaying graphics.